# Entity Framework cycle of data

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an Account object, which has many Transactions related to it.

In one method, I get all transactions for a particular account.

```
    var transactionlines = (from p in Context.account_transaction
                                  .Include("account_transaction_line")
                                //  .Include("Account")
                                  .Include("account.z_account_type")
                                  .Include("account.institution")
                                  .Include("third_party")
                                  .Include("third_party.z_third_party_type")
                                  .Include("z_account_transaction_type")
                                  .Include("account_transaction_line.transaction_sub_category")
                                  .Include("account_transaction_line.transaction_sub_category.transaction_category")
                                  .Include("z_account_transaction_entry_type")
                                  .Include("account_transaction_line.cost_centre")
                            where p.account_id == accountId
                                  && p.deleted == null

                            select p).ToList();
```

This is meant to return me a list of transactions, with their related objects. I then pass each object to a Translator, which translates them into data transfer objects, which are then passed back to my main application.

```
 public TransactionDto TranslateTransaction(account_transaction source)
        {
            LogUserActivity("in TranslateTransaction");

            var result = new TransactionDto
            {
                Id = source.id,
                Version = source.version,
                AccountId = source.account_id,
               // Account = TranslateAccount(source.account, false),
                ThirdPartyId = source.third_party_id,
                ThirdParty = TranslateThirdParty(source.third_party),
                Amount = source.transaction_amount,
                EntryTypeId = source.account_transaction_entry_type_id,
                EntryType = new ReferenceItemDto
                {
                    Id = source.account_transaction_entry_type_id,
                    Description = source.z_account_transaction_entry_type.description,
                    Deleted = source.z_account_transaction_entry_type.deleted != null

                },
                Notes = source.notes,
                TransactionDate = source.transaction_date,
                TransactionTypeId = source.account_transaction_type_id,
                TransactionType = new ReferenceItemDto
                {
                    Id = source.z_account_transaction_type.id,
                    Description = source.z_account_transaction_type.description,
                    Deleted = source.z_account_transaction_type.deleted != null
                }
            };
... return my object
}
```

The problem is:

An account has Transactions, and a Transaction therefore belongs to an Account. It seems my translators are being called way too much, and reloading a lot of data because of this.

When I load my transaction object, it's 'account' property has a'transactions' propery, which has a list of all the transactions associated to that account. Each transaction then has an account property... and those account peroprties again, have a list of all the transactions... and on and on it goes.

Is there a way I can limit the loading to one level or something?

I have this set:

```
Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

I was hoping my 'Includes' would be all that is loaded... Don't load 'un-included' related data?

As requested, here is my TranslateAccount method:

```
public AccountDto TranslateAccount(account p, bool includeCardsInterestRateDataAndBalance)
{
    LogUserActivity("in TranslateAccount");
    if (p == null)
        return null;

    var result =
        new AccountDto
        {
            Id = p.id,
            Description = p.description,
            PortfolioId = p.institution.account_portfolio_id,
            AccountNumber = p.account_number,
            Institution = TranslateInstitution(p.institution),
            AccountType = new ReferenceItemDto
            {
                Id = p.account_type_id,
                Description = p.z_account_type.description
            },
            AccountTypeId = p.account_type_id,
            InstitutionId = p.institution_id,
            MinimumBalance = p.min_balance,
            OpeningBalance = p.opening_balance,
            OpeningDate = p.opening_date
        };

    if (includeCardsInterestRateDataAndBalance)
    {
        // Add the assigned cards collection
        foreach (var card in p.account_card)
        {
            result.Cards.Add(new AccountCardDto
                {
                    Id = card.id,
                    AccountId = card.account_id,
                    Active = card.active,
                    CardHolderName = card.card_holder_name,
                    CardNumber = card.card_number,
                    ExpiryDate = card.expiry
                });
        }

        // Populate the current interest rate
        result.CurrentRate = GetCurrentInterestRate(result.Id);

        // Add all rates to the account
        foreach (var rate in p.account_rate)
        {
            result.Rates.Add(
                new AccountRateDto
                    {
                        Id = rate.id,
                        Description = rate.description,
                        Deleted = rate.deleted != null,
                        AccountId = rate.account_id,
                        EndDate = rate.end_date,
                        Rate = rate.rate,
                        StartDate = rate.start_date
                    });
        }
        result.CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance(result.Id);
    }
    LogUserActivity("out TranslateAccount");
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `TranslateAccount`?

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 0):

The entity framework context maintains a cache of data that has been pulled out of the database. Regardless of lazy loading being enabled/disabled, you can call `Transaction.Account.Transactions[0].Account.Transactions[0]...` as much as you want without loading anything else from the database.

The problem is not in the cyclical nature of entity framework objects - it is somewhere in the logic of your translation objects.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just can't work out why my 'Account' model has a List of Transactions associated to it. I'd prefer it not to have this.... It seems the relationship is going two ways. An "account has many transactions associated to it", hence the relationship. Can I not stop this from being part of the 'account' model? I just want the 'Transaction belongs to an Account' relationship to work.

Comment: You can't stop it from being part of the model (entity framework always creates two-way navigation properties), but you can change the accessibility of the Account.Transactions property to Private using the entity framework designer.  That would prevent it from showing up anywhere.